# What's the more appropriate collection to use in this case?

Tags: java, list, collections

I need a linked list that can be accessed by any index and put an element in any index.
The problem is that ArrayList and LinkedList's add method has this behaviour:
"Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)."

This is an undesirable behaviour, I want the current element to get replaced if used.
What collection should I use then?

Comment: You should not use `add()` method to replace an element.That what [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and use its set() method. If that's the only behavior that you want, it would more lightweight perhaps to make your own ListNode, then implement add(E) and set(E).

Comment: LinkedList<String> memory = new LinkedList<String>();
    memory.set(125, "Putting an element in the position 125");

this return an OutOfBoundsException. As I said, I want to access and put elements in ANY index, what should I do?

Comment: Is your intended behavior many, many empty nodes? It seems like you could almost use a map for that behavior that you want, because then you could have 125 map to "putting an index..." and you don't need to have 124 empty nodes.

Comment: never heard about maps before, I'll check it out, thanks!